# Does AutoMigration() also give the NOT NULL attribute on the database side?

Tags: go, go-gorm

In GORM, does `AutoMigration()` also give the NOT NULL attribute on the database side?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: **No**

So if you do not define `not null` (using GORM field tags) to that particular field, GORM will not add `NOT NULL` constraint to the field on db side. Except for the primary key. By default, PK will be defined as `NOT NULL` field.

**Way to define the field as `NOT NULL` in GORM**:

```golang
type User struct {
    ...
    Email string `gorm:"not null"` // NOT NULL 
    ...
}
```

For more, see official documentation of GORM: [Field Tags](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Fields-Tags)

Comment: Thanks, but why is `AutoMigrate` not updating it? I can still see `null` on those fields, which I changed to `not null`.

Comment: Need to see the code first. So that I can investigate. Can you edit the question by including the codes? Or a playground link will suffice.